# Is there a method for quickly determining how a CSV file has been sorted?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have opened a CSV file in Notepad containing data on Building Permits Issued in a metropolitan area that has 20 columns and over 33,000 rows. It is not immediately obvious how the file has been sorted. It may just be a data dump but I'm not sure. Therefore I'm wondering if there is a best way to quickly tell how the data has been sorted it if at all. Is there a method for this? I am currently a Data Analytics student learning data analysis with python, pandas, Jupyter Notebooks, etc

Comment: why is it important to know the sorting? they are samples of a dataset, ordering is unimportant

Comment: `pandas.read_csv` reads the file in, as-is, without sorting.

Comment: You can check if a Series is sorted with pandas.Series.is_monotonic. So, you can load the the file in pandas and then iterate over the columns to check if any column is sorted. E.g.: to check for increasing order df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic), and to check for decreasing order df.apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_decreasing)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a hypothesis about the sort order (or uniqueness) for multiple fields in your data frame.  You could test with the MultiIndex.

```
fields = ['a', 'c', 'x']  # select fields of interest from data frame `df`
assert pd.MultiIndex.from_frame( df[fields] ).is_monotonic
assert pd.MultiIndex.from_frame( df[fields] ).is_unique
```